# WinStore App Listview: Avoiding multiple lines with the same name

Tags: c#, xml, linq, windows-store-apps

I am developing Windows Store App. I have such XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<music>
  <singer>
    <name>Coldplay</name>
    <song>Scientist</song>
    <lyrics>lol lalala</lyrics>
  </singer>
  <singer>
    <name>Coldplay</name>
    <song>test2</song>
    <lyrics>lol lalala2</lyrics>
  </singer>
  <singer>
    <name>another</name>
    <song>şarkı</song>
    <lyrics>lol lalala3</lyrics>
  </singer>
</music>
```

in C# code, "lvSingers" is my listview. I binded singers' name there.

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string musicXMLPath = Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "Assets/test.xml");
    XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load(musicXMLPath);
    var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("singer")
               select new Singer
               {
                   name = (string)query.Element("name"),
                   song = (string)query.Element("song"),
                   akor = (string)query.Element("lyrics")
               };
    lvSingers.ItemsSource = data;
}

}
```

When i run this code, i am getting multiple singer names, i want to avoid that. Example:

```
Coldplay
Coldplay
another
```

I just want to have ONLY one Coldplay over there. Short of all i want is distinct output. 
I would appreciate your feedback and help. Regards...

Comment: The SO question here has a good sample you can use; take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021679/linq-to-xml-noob-question-distinct-and-order-by-on-attributes

Comment: Thanks for help but it does not seem to work. I already tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, even though the artist name is repeated, you have distinct items since the songs are different for Coldplay. So, you could bind your ItemsSource to a distinct list, and set a SelectedArtist property using something like below:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Music.xml");
var data = doc.Descendants("singer").Select(x => new Singer {
    Name = (string)x.Element("name"),
    Song = (string)x.Element("song"),
    Lyrics = (string)x.Element("lyrics")
});
List<string> dataToBind = data.Select(x => x.Name).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Good; I was actually just preparing a WPF sample app to make sure, but the sample did work in my console test app.

Answer (score 1):

I'm away from my win8 dev machine.  I'm not sure how listview handles grouping.  You can try the following.

```
    var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("singer")
               select new Singer
               {
                   name = (string)query.Element("name"),
                   song = (string)query.Element("song"),
                   akor = (string)query.Element("lyrics")
               }.GroupBy(ex => ex.name);
```

Depending on what you need, you may just want to send the listview a datasource that only contains the names.

```
lvSingers.ItemsSource = data.Select(ex => (string)ex.name).Distinct();
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm but "from query in loadedData.Descendants("singer")
               select new Singer
               {
                   name = (string)query.Element("name"),
                   song = (string)query.Element("song"),
                   akor = (string)query.Element("lyrics")
               }"
should be in parantheses.
Regards :)